# Haskell - Group list elements with foldr function

Tags: list, haskell, fold

This is for an assignment in Haskell.
We have been tasked with defining various functions using the foldr function.

We have been given a type:

```
group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

and been asked to define it such that:

```
group [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5] = [[1], [2,2], [3], [4,4,4], [5]]
group [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,1,1,1] = [[1], [2,2], [3], [4,4,4], [5], [1,1,1]]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
group = foldr (\x xs -> if x == head (head xs) then (x : head xs) : xs else (x : []) : (head xs) : xs )
```

But when I try to load this into ghci interpreter I get the following error message:

```
Couldn't match type `[a0] -> [a]' with `[[a]]'
Expected type: [a] -> [[a]]
  Actual type: [a] -> [a0] -> [a]
In the return type of a call of `foldr'
Probable cause: `foldr' is applied to too few arguments
In the expression:
  foldr
    (\ x xs
       -> if x == head (head xs) then
              (x : head xs) : xs
          else
              (x : []) : (head xs) : xs)
In an equation for `group':
    group
      = foldr
          (\ x xs
             -> if x == head (head xs) then
                    (x : head xs) : xs
                else
                    (x : []) : (head xs) : xs)
```

If anyone could explain any reasons why my code isn't working as I expect it to, that would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: it says you right there: you need an additional argument ... try whatever you want to get if you do `group []` ;) (but beware there will be other issues ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are on  the right track so I'll try to write your idea a bit nicer. What I want to say is this: you should pull out the first argument of `foldr` into an function and do pattern-matching again:

```
group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
group = foldr f undefined
  where f x []        = undefined
        f x (ys@(y:_):yss)
          | x == y    = undefined
          | otherwise = undefined
```

this should do - now you *only* have to put in the right stuff where I put `undefined` :)

I'll come back later and finish it

---

well I guess you gave up or something - anyway here is one solution:

```
group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
group = foldr f []
  where f x []        = [[x]]
        f x (ys@(y:_):yss)
          | x == y     = (x:ys):yss
          | otherwise = [x]:ys:yss
```

and a few examples:

```
λ> group []
[]
λ> group [1]
[[1]]
λ> group [1,1]
[[1,1]]
λ> group [1,2,1]
[[1],[2],[1]]
λ> group [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5]
[[1],[2,2],[3],[4,4,4],[5]]
```

note that `f`s patterns are not exhaustive (which is no problem - think about why) - of course you can extent it if you want (and if you don't agree with `group [] = []` than you have to.

Comment: This is too strict, in my opinion.

Comment: @dfeuer probably yes - but IMO it's the idea I thought to see in James attempt brought to *life* ;) - I don't pretend to give *best* answers ^^

Comment: Thanks for your response, your answer makes sense and is in fact almost identical to the answer model answer on a website that zuko32 posted:

    pack :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
    pack = foldr func []
        where func x []     = [[x]]
              func x (y:xs) =
                  if x == (head y) then ((x:y):xs) else ([x]:y:xs)

Comment: I have written my own code out in the same form so I am better able to compare the differences between my code and this model answer.
I believe my big mistake was reading in two variables x and xs rather than x and a list: (y:xs).
I also did not set the base case properly where f x [] == [[]], and I was wasting time appending x onto the empty set when I could have just written [x].
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention that if I am not wrong, this is the problem 9 from the 99 haskell problems that can be found here: https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/ 
For every problem, it has a bunch of solutions(usually) and since Carsten presented a great solution, you can go there and see other solutions so you can get different ideas on how the same thing can be achieved in various ways!

Comment: You are correct it is the same problem, thanks for directing me to this.

Comment: @James Nothing man. I think it is a very good practice for Haskell programmers, so you migh be interested in trying more of these problems. :)